# Problemas en la recepción de json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo en Laravel el siguiente código ,en la vista que recoge los datos ,cada id se descarga en el var data para remitirla al controller

```
$('#formPago').validate({
        rules: {
            fecha: { required:true},
            tesoreriadefinicion: { required:true },
            pagoimporte: { required:true },
            conceptopago: { required:true }
        },
        submitHandler: function() {
            //-- Comprobación de los datos.
            $('#frmAddPago').modal( 'hide' );
            var data = {"suscriptor_id":$("#id_id").val(),
                                          "pago" : $("#input-pago-id").val(),
                                   "factura_id" : $("#_id").val(),
                               "proveedor_id": $("#proveedor_id").val(),
                                 "acreedor_id": $("#acreedor_id").val(),
                                         "fecha" : $("#input-fecha-pago").val(),
                               "tesoreria_id" : $("#input-tesoreria").val(),
                             "pagoimporte" : $("#input-pago-importe").val(),
                                    "concepto" : $("#input-p-concepto").val(),
                               "masconcepto": $("#input-p-masconcepto").val(), 
                                        "saldo"  : $("#input-saldo").val(),
                                       "_token" : $("#_token").val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '/facturapagos/insertorupdate',
                data: data,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function( pago ){
                console.log(pago);
```

La recepción del request se produce en el correspondiente controller en la siguiente function. aquí diferencio cuando es update de create

```
    public function insertorupdate( Request $request) {
    $datos = $request->all();
    Log::Info("factura pago controller insert or update");
    Log::Info($datos);
     if ( (int) $datos['pago']>0 ) {
        // Modifica los datos.
        $pago =$this->repoFacturaPago->getModel->find($datos['pago']);
        $pago->fecha = $datos['fecha'];
        $pago->suscriptor_id=$datos['suscriptor_id'];
        $pago->proveedor_id=$datos['proveedor_id'];
        $pago->acreedor_id=$datos['acreedor_id'];
        $pago->subcuenta_id =$datos['tesoreria_id'];
        $pago->pagoimporte = $datos['pagoimporte'];
        $pago->concepto =$datos['concepto'];      
        $pago->conceptodos =$datos['masconcepto'];      
        $pago->save();
        $this->repoActividad->create( "facturapagos" , "modificar" , $pago );
        $this->repoRepositorio->store( "facturapagos" , $pago );
        $this->saldo($datos['factura_id'],$pago);
    } else {
        // Añade un nuevo pago
    $pago =$this->repoFacturaPago->create($datos);
    Log::Info("despues de repofactura pago create");
    Log::Info($pago);

    $this->saldo($datos['factura_id'],$pago);
    //$this->contabilizaPago($datos,$pago->id);
    }
   
}

/*Calcula el saldo de las facturas 
 * 
 */
public function saldo($facturaid,$pago){
    $saldo=($this->repoFacturaRecibida->getModel()->where("id","=",$facturaid)->first()->saldo());
    $pago->saldo =$saldo;
    Log::Info("pago que se devuelve");
    Log::Info($pago);
    return json_encode($pago);
```

La Información que se recibe mediante Log::Info es la siguiente:
La function insertorupdate recibe el request

```
[2020-10-08 17:13:19] local.INFO: factura pago controller insert or update  
[2020-10-08 17:13:19] local.INFO: array (
'suscriptor_id' => '7',
'pago' => '0',
'factura_id' => '477',
'proveedor_id' => '0',
'acreedor_id' => '1007',
'fecha' => '2020-10-08',
'tesoreria_id' => '2',
'pagoimporte' => '10',
'concepto' => '19',
'masconcepto' => 'factura 789456 pedro sl.',
'saldo' => NULL,
'_token' => 'D8uFRpi7d3wBqtZDGJqhmDqTNr6zMbTeEYd6JNgJ',
)
```

Y se devuelve a la vista  mediante return json_encode($pago);

```
[2020-10-08 17:13:19] local.INFO: pago que se devuelve  
[2020-10-08 17:13:19] local.INFO: {"fecha":"2020-10-08", 
"suscriptor_id":7,"factura_id":"477",
"diariolinea_id":0,"subcuenta_id":"2",
"pagoimporte":"10","proveedor_id":"0",
"concepto":"19","conceptodos":"factura 789456 pedro sl.", 
"updated_at":"2020-10-08 17:13:19","created_at":"2020-10-08 17:13:19","
 id":58,"saldo":-2515.76}
```

Aparentemente el código llega a enviar json_encode a la vista ,pero ésta no lo recibe y la consola arroja el siguiente error:

```
<empty string> 477:1317:9
 Uncaught TypeError: pago.fecha is undefined
success http://localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:1325
jQuery 6
    u
    fireWith
    k
    n
    send
    ajax
submitHandler http://localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:1311
jQuery 11
    d
    validate
    dispatch
    handle
    add
    De
    each
    each
    De
    on
    validate
<anonymous> http://localhost/facturarecibidas/edit/477:1289
jQuery 13
    l
    c
    setTimeout handler*a/<
    u
    fireWith
    fire
    u
    fireWith
    ready
    _
    EventListener.handleEvent*
    <anonymous>
    <anonymous>
```

477:1325:25

​

Comment: Parece que sobran los corchetes con fecha/hora y `local.INFO:`

Comment: @triby Local::Info   es el resultado de Log::Info  es a título informativo ,no forma parte del código

Comment: En la petición AJAX agrega la captura de error para ver porqué está fallando.

Comment: Parece que **aparte del JSON** estás sacando **algo más** por pantalla que está **rompiendo el JSON**. No conozco Laravel y no sé a qué nivel se imprimen los Logs que tienes en el código, si esos Logs entra en el flujo de salida de pantalla debes saber que está rompiendo tu JSON y eso produce error.

Comment: @Triby    Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: getResponseHeader(e), getAllResponseHeaders: getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: setRequestHeader(e, t), overrideMimeType: overrideMimeType(e), statusCode: statusCode(e), abort: abort(e), state: state(), always: always(), catch: catch(e)
, … }
477:1221:9
parsererror 477:1222:9
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    jQuery 3
        Ut
        k
        n

Comment: @A Cedano El tema está en saber ¿ que se está enviando?  antes del json_encode  aparece {"fecha":"2020-10-08", 
"suscriptor_id":7,"factura_id":"477",
"diariolinea_id":0,"subcuenta_id":"2",
"pagoimporte":"10","proveedor_id":"0",
"concepto":"19","conceptodos":"factura 789456 pedro sl.", 
"updated_at":"2020-10-08 17:13:19","created_at":"2020-10-08 17:13:19","
 id":58,"saldo":-2515.76}

Comment: @ A Cedano: en Laravel ,hasta donde yo se, los logs no interfieren en el código sólo ofrecen información del resultado del mismo ,al menos a mi nunca me han dado problemas de interferencia

Comment: @Triby    Te envío lo que veo más problemático ,observa es status  200 state: state()
​​
length: 0
​​
name: "state"
​​
prototype: {…}
​​​
constructor: function state()​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
<prototype>: function ()
​
status: 200
​
statusCode: function statusCode(e)
​
statusText: "OK"
​
then: function then(t, r, i)​
<prototype>: Object { … }
477:1233:9

Comment: Al parecer, tienes una salida después del _JSON_ y esa es la que impide que se interprete.

Comment: @Triby Te vuelvo a enviar el ajax , como verás después de  return Json_encode($pago); sólo tengo  console.log(pago)                                      
                 $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '/facturapagos/insertorupdate',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function( pago ){
console.log(pago);

Comment: Prueba cambiando `datatype: "html"` y edita la pregunta para poner lo que obtienes con `console.log(pago);`

Comment: @treiby el error  parece ser que está en devolver json_endoce($pago) desde una function  diferenta a la que recibe el $request ,he pasado la instrucción desde saldoFacturas a insertorupdate y los datos entrados se reflejan en pantalla, agradecería comentario  sobre el tema. gracias

Comment: Estás llamando a la función que genera el _JSON_, pero no lo asignas a una variable: `$this->saldo($datos['factura_id'],$pago);`, ¿cómo y dónde es que envías la salida?

Comment: @triby La salida la envío 1ª) después del ajax a success: function( pago ){
                console.log(pago); para ver el objeto . 2ª) a un html en javascript, t e envío las primeras líneas  $("#input-saldo").html("Saldo : "+toFormat(pago["saldo"],2));
                        var id = "tr-"+pago['id'];
                        var tr ="";
                        if ( parseInt($("#input-pago-id").val())>0 ){
                        } else {
                            tr+="<tr data-id='"+pago['id']+"' id='tr-"+pago['id']+"'>";
                        }
                        tr+="<td>"